# SQL Update with Min and Sum and Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-server-2017

I'm looking to write an update that will correct a flag that's gone astray.

I'd like to set the PRIMARY_FLAG = 1 for the min(TABLE_ID) grouped by ACCOUNT_NUMBER where the sum(PRIMARY_FLAG) <> 1 grouped by ACCOUNT_NUMBER.

Here is what the table looks like now:

```
TABLE_ID   ACCOUNT_NUMBER   PRIMARY_FLAG
--------   --------------   ------------
1          ABC123           0 
2          ABC123           1
3          ABC123           0
4          987XYZ           0
5          987XYZ           0
6          987XYZ           0
7          5A5B5C           1
8          5A5B5C           1
9          5A5B5C           0
10         5A5B5C           0
```

Here's what I want it to look like after the update:

```
TABLE_ID   ACCOUNT_NUMBER   PRIMARY_FLAG
--------   --------------   ------------
1          ABC123           0 
2          ABC123           1
3          ABC123           0
4          987XYZ           1
5          987XYZ           0
6          987XYZ           0
7          5A5B5C           1
8          5A5B5C           0
9          5A5B5C           0
10         5A5B5C           0
```

Scenario 1 - TABLE_ID 1, 2, 3 with ACCOUNT_NUMBER = ABC123 is already correct and I do not want the update to touch it.

Scenario 2 - ACCOUNT_NUMBER = 987XYZ, none of the TABLE_ID have a PRIMARY_FLAG = 1, so update will set PRIMARY_FLAG = 1 where TABLE_ID = 4

Scenario 3 - ACCOUNT_NUMBER = 5A5B5C has multiple TABLE_ID = 1, so update would leave TABLE_ID 7 but SET PRIMARY_FLAG = 0 where TABLE_ID = 8

Help is appreciate!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic method:

```
update t
    set primary_flag = (case when t.id = (select min(t2.id)
                                          from t t2
                                          where t2.account_number = t.account_number
                                         )
                             then 1 else 0
                        end)
    where t.account_number in (select t2.acount_number
                               from t t2
                               group by t2.acount_number
                               having sum(t2.primary_flag) <> 1
                              );
```

This is standard SQL and will work in most databases.  However, specific databases might have more concise or efficient methods of doing the same thing.

Comment: I like your analysis of a generic query too.  For larger queries, I needed the inner join to save memory from duplicate query results.  I still gave an uptick since it would work as an alternative option.

Answer (score 1):

Join the table to the query that returns the minimum table_id for each account_number that needs to be updated:

```
update t 
set t.primary_flag = case when t.table_id = g.minid then 1 else 0 end
from tablename t inner join (
  select account_number, min(table_id) minid
  from tablename
  group by account_number
  having sum(primary_flag) <> 1
) g on g.account_number = t.account_number;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e760bf7219de6a2d75dff60da31a4638).
Or with a CTE:

```
with cte as (
  select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by account_number order by table_id) rn,
    sum(primary_flag) over (partition by account_number) total
  from tablename  
)
update cte 
set primary_flag = case when rn = 1 then 1 else 0 end
where total <> 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1689626f89ddaa65fec152959caedae8).
To avoid unnecessary updates for the rows that do not need to be updated:

```
with cte as (
  select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by account_number order by table_id) rn,
    sum(primary_flag) over (partition by account_number) total
  from tablename  
)
update cte 
set primary_flag = abs(primary_flag - 1)
where (total <> 1) and ((rn = 1 and primary_flag = 0) or (rn > 1 and primary_flag = 1))
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d85bace82b5903a218022a21557fd555).
Results:

```
> TABLE_ID | ACCOUNT_NUMBER | PRIMARY_FLAG
> -------: | :------------- | -----------:
>        1 | ABC123         |            0
>        2 | ABC123         |            1
>        3 | ABC123         |            0
>        4 | 987XYZ         |            1
>        5 | 987XYZ         |            0
>        6 | 987XYZ         |            0
>        7 | 5A5B5C         |            1
>        8 | 5A5B5C         |            0
>        9 | 5A5B5C         |            0
>       10 | 5A5B5C         |            0
```

Comment: This is an impressive technique for identifying the first duplicate parent in a series!  And it runs very fast!  Especially since it gets around the GROUP BY read only query by using an INNER JOIN to itself!!!

Comment: I'm using MySql and it works the same.